# How come RAMdisk not visible via "lsblk -all"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, mount

How come RAMdisk not visible via "lsblk -all" ?

The manual says:

```
man lsblk
-a, --all
Disable all built-in filters and
list all empty devices and
RAM disk devices too.
```

using
`neofetch --stdout | grep 'OS:'`
result:
OS: Kubuntu 22.10 x86_64

.

Does anyone else have the same problem?

```
df          # shows ramdisk 
lsblk -all  # does not show ramdisk
```

.

background 1 :
`dpkg -l |grep 'util-linux' |awk '{print $3}'` 
2.38-4ubuntu1

.

background 2 :
`lsblk --version` 
lsblk from util-linux 2.38

.

background 3 :
made a 25GB ramdisk1 with 3 commands:

```
sudo mkdir     /mnt/ramdisk1
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/ramdisk1
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,size=25G tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk1
```

.

background 4 :
made 2 files 22GB and 1GB on ramdisk1

```
time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ramdisk1/zero22G bs=1M count=22000
time sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ramdisk1/zero01G bs=1M count=1000
```

.

background 5 :
confirmed ramdisk1

```
df     |grep -i 'blocks\|ramdisk'

Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            26214400  23552000   2662400  90% /mnt/ramdisk1
```

.

background 6 :
confirmed ramdisk1 using GB

```
df -BG |grep --color=always -i 'sd\|nv\|blocks\|ram'

Filesystem     1G-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                25G   23G        3G  90% /mnt/ramdisk1
...
```

.

background 7 :

```
lsblk -all
```

does not show ramdisk.

```
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0       7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1       7:1    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
loop2       7:2    0 238.5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1969
loop3       7:3    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop4       7:4    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop5       7:5    0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17336
loop6       7:6    0     0B  0 loop
loop7       7:7    0     0B  0 loop
sda         8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
sda1        8:1    0   512M  0 part
sda2        8:2    0 118.7G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                    /
sdb         8:16   0   1.4T  0 disk
sdb1        8:17   0   1.4T  0 part /media/x/s1397GB
sdc         8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk
sdd         8:48   1  28.9G  0 disk
sdd1        8:49   1     4G  0 part
sdd2        8:50   1   4.2M  0 part
sdd3        8:51   1   300K  0 part
sdd4        8:52   1  24.9G  0 part /media/x/writable
sde         8:64   1  29.2G  0 disk
sde1        8:65   1  29.2G  0 part /media/x/x_FAT_32
nvme0n1   259:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 465.3G  0 part
```

.

```
df          # shows ramdisk
lsblk -all  # does not show ramdisk
```

.

How come RAMdisk not visible via "lsblk -all" ?

--

Comment: A guess; you're using `tmpfs` - which makes the ramdisk be in same category as `/run`, `/dev/shm`, `/run/lock` and `/run/user/` - which all apparently are filtered out.

Comment: Kamil Maciorowski (This probably is not related to the issue though.) _
Correct not related.  4 tests done:
```lsblk --all |wc -l``` = 19 and
```lsblk -all |wc -l``` = 19 and
```lsblk -a |wc -l``` = 19 and
```lsblk  |wc -l``` = 18 with loop8 gone.
No RAMdisk found with ```lsblk --all```. but
RAMdisk found with: ```df -BG |grep --color=always -i 'sd\|nv\|blocks\|ram'```

Comment: Hannu ... which all apparently are filtered out. _
How to make a RAMdisk?  Which web page?  i have tested many ways to make a ramdisk.
All with same result of - No RAMdisk found with ```lsblk --all``` or ```lsblk -a```. but
RAMdisk found with: ```df -BG |grep --color=always -i 'sd\|nv\|blocks\|ram'```
Results are opposite to manual ```man lsblk -a, --all  Disable all built-in filters and
list all empty devices and RAM disk devices too. ``` Suggestions? How to make a RAMdisk?

Answer (score 0):

#### Side note

Your `lsblk -all` is equivalent to `lsblk -a -l -l` i.e. to `lsblk --all --list --list`, not to sole `lsblk --all`.

---

#### Short answer

> How come RAMdisk not visible via `lsblk -all`?

`lsblk` lists block devices. Your "RAMdisk" is `tmpfs`, it *does not* use any block device whatsoever.

---

#### Explanation and research

`mount -t tmpfs …` creates and mounts a filesystem that exists in RAM, not in some block device. `mount -t ramfs …` is similar.

With `modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=…` you can create `/dev/ram0` which *is* a block device that uses RAM. By itself it's not a filesystem though. To store files in it, you need to create a filesystem (like in any other block device) and to mount the filesystem somewhere. The files will exist in the filesystem existing in the block device existing in RAM.

In case of `tmpfs` files exist in a filesystem existing in RAM. There is no block device between the filesystem and RAM. This is why `lsblk --all` prints no entry related to `tmpfs`. It's not something gets filtered out. There is no block device in this scheme *at all*.

I have actually tested `lsblk --all` with ramdisks that do use block devices. In my Debian `lsblk --all` does show `ram0`. I also use [`zram0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram) for swap and my `lsblk --all` shows `zram0` as well. It looks *if* there is a block device then `lsblk --all` will show it.

---

#### Evolution

The above research agrees with this [article on Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ramfs) that gives some insight into how these things evolved:

> With ramfs, there is no backing store. […] The older "ram disk" mechanism created a synthetic block device out of an area of ram and used it as backing store for a filesystem. […] The ram disk is simply unnecessary. […] A ramfs derivative called tmpfs was created […].

The older mechanism is the one with `/dev/ram0` or so. At some point the unnecessary layer of the block device was removed and `ramfs` was invented. Then `ramfs` was improved and `tmpfs` arose.

Comment: Kamil typed ```modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=…```, i typed 
       ```sudo modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=25G /dev/ram0```, computer said 
```modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'brd': Invalid argument```. 
Clarification is needed.

Comment: @joseph22 The parameters are described [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/blockdev/ramdisk.html). Valid example: `sudo modprobe brd rd_nr=1 rd_size=40960`